# Undefined Reference to .. - mingw - winxp - eclipse juno

Tags: c++, c, windows-xp, mingw, eclipse-juno

Well as the title says, I keep getting an Undefined Reference to error but I don't know why..

I have a main routine which has the header of the function I wanna use included, which therefore is included by the cpp file which defines the function.
I also included the path to the project settings

I know I should post code but I am not allowed to do that but still hope I can get some hints on solving this error.

Thanks in advance

```
UART_write(UARTvar, LVL);  //This is where I call the function

int UART_write(int uart, const char* var);//Declaration in the header

int UART_write(int uart, const char* var)
{
return (int)1;//just for testing
}
```

undefined reference to `UART_write'

Comment: Also when I press F3(which is used to go to the declaration/definition, it finds the declaration and also the definition)

Comment: It misses the needed library to link.

Comment: Can you me more specific? Exact error, part of your code?

Comment: "I know I should post code but I am not allowed to do that but still hope I can get some hints on solving this error." -1 Too localized.

Comment: Either there is an overload missing that the editor doesn't notice, or you are not linking all the files. We can't tell without seeing the error message and the source.

Comment: Well I am linking them in the project settings(added the include paths of the header files)

Comment: @Bo Persson - the project is so proprietary that even error messages should be kept secret.

Comment: @SChepurin: The error message is there since 29 minutes

Comment: @aaj07 - Nope. You should copy-paste the exact error message output.

Comment: @aaj07 In addition to updating the include paths, you also have to update linker settings to list the path + name of the library which implements `UART_write`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following project structure:

**header.h:**

```
#ifndef _HEADER_H_
#define _HEADER_H_

int UART_write(int uart, const char* var);

#endif
```

**main.c:**

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    ...
    UART_write(UARTvar, LVL);
    ...
}
```

So please be sure that you have not defined `_HEADER_H_` in any other place, as in this case `UART_write()` prototype will not be included in build.

Also please check if the `UART_write()` prototype is not placed between `#if` or `#ifdef` and `#endif` preprocessor commands.

And the last one, you can check above by adding `#error "This code is compiled"` before the `UART_write()` prototype in your header. If this part of code is compiled, so you will get compilation error `This code is compiled`.

Comment: Thanks for this hints :)
Found the error: somehow it couldn't manage that the file was a *.cpp so after changing it to *.c it worked.